# unable to build and deploy jar file using drools workbench dashboard for deploying it to kieserver. Process stuck on building the jar spinner

Tags: java, docker, drools, jbpm

I have been using this command to run the docker:

`- docker run -p 8085:8080 -p 8001:8001 -e JAVA_OPTS="-server -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8" --name jbpm-server-full jboss/jbpm-server-full:7.40.0.Final`

I think it is a maven problem. drools unable to build the jar so that I can deploy it on kieserver. This process is also not working for sample project that it provide. Although I can do the build and deploy using manual setup(download zip and place it in wildfly and run) but i'm getting issues using docker setup. Any help is highly appreciated.

I tried to add this in host.xml

```
<system-properties>
  <property name="org.uberfire.nio.git.dir" value="/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/.niogit" boot-time="false"/>
</system-properties>
```

but doesn't work.

> [image: Blockquote]

in log I found it unusual:

```
15:27:30,380 WARN  [org.kie.server.services.impl.controller.DefaultRestControllerImpl] (KieServer-ControllerConnect) Exception encountered while syncing with controller at http://localhost:8080/business-central/rest/controller/server/sample-server error Read timed out
15:27:31,040 WARN  [org.jboss.errai.config.rebind.EnvUtil] (MSC service thread 1-3) The property errai.security.user_on_hostpage_enabled has been set multiple times.
15:27:31,042 WARN  [org.jboss.errai.config.rebind.EnvUtil] (MSC service thread 1-3) The property errai.class_scanning_extension has been set multiple times.



15:27:32,186 WARN  [org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenSettings] (MSC service thread 1-3) Environment variable M2_HOME is not set
15:27:34,340 INFO  [org.uberfire.ext.metadata.io.IndexerDispatcher] (Thread-141) Completed indexing 1 events for indexer [id=org.uberfire.ext.metadata.io.CoreIndexer] in cluster [KClusterImpl [clusterId=dashbuilder/datasets/master]].
15:27:35,677 WARN  [org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.RefDirectory] (MSC service thread 1-3) Unable to remove path /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/.niogit/.archetypes/org-kie-templates-base-kie-project-1-0-0-TEMPLATE.git/logs/refs/remotes/origin: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/.niogit/.archetypes/org-kie-templates-base-kie-project-1-0-0-TEMPLATE.git/logs/refs/remotes/origin
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:92)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:116)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.implDelete(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:249)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.delete(AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:105)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.delete(Files.java:1141)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.RefDirectory.delete(RefDirectory.java:1289)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.RefDirectory.delete(RefDirectory.java:1273)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.RefDirectory.delete(RefDirectory.java:694)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.RefDirectoryUpdate.doDelete(RefDirectoryUpdate.java:153)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.eclipse.jgit.lib.RefUpdate$2.execute(RefUpdate.java:680)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.eclipse.jgit.lib.RefUpdate.updateImpl(RefUpdate.java:774)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.eclipse.jgit.lib.RefUpdate.delete(RefUpdate.java:677)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.eclipse.jgit.lib.RefUpdate.delete(RefUpdate.java:649)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.uberfire.java.nio.fs.jgit.util.commands.RemoveRemote.execute(RemoveRemote.java:51)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.uberfire.java.nio.fs.jgit.util.GitImpl.removeRemote(GitImpl.java:594)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.kie.workbench.common.screens.archetype.mgmt.backend.service.ArchetypeServiceImpl.cleanUpOrigin(ArchetypeServiceImpl.java:708)   


16:20:36,841 ERROR [org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenEmbedder] (Thread-198) Unable to build MavenEmbedder: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: java.util.NoSuchElementException
      role: org.apache.maven.execution.MavenExecutionRequestPopulator
  roleHint: 
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:267)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:249)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.PlexusComponentProvider.lookup(PlexusComponentProvider.java:42)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenEmbedder.buildMavenExecutionRequest(MavenEmbedder.java:142)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenEmbedder.init(MavenEmbedder.java:104)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenEmbedder.<init>(MavenEmbedder.java:99)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenEmbedder.<init>(MavenEmbedder.java:91)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenEmbedder.<init>(MavenEmbedder.java:85)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenProjectLoader.parseMavenPom(MavenProjectLoader.java:70)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenProjectLoader.loadMavenProject(MavenProjectLoader.java:179)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.appformer.maven.integration.Aether.getAether(Aether.java:76)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.appformer.maven.integration.MavenRepository.getMavenRepository(MavenRepository.java:95)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenEmbedder.tryRemoveLocalArtifact(MavenEmbedder.java:342)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenEmbedder.readProject(MavenEmbedder.java:319)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenProjectLoader.parseMavenPom(MavenProjectLoader.java:91)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenProjectLoader.parseMavenPom(MavenProjectLoader.java:84)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.appformer.maven.integration.MavenPomModelGenerator.parse(MavenPomModelGenerator.java:34)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.appformer.maven.support.PomModel$Parser.parse(PomModel.java:110)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildPomModel(KieBuilderImpl.java:591)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.init(KieBuilderImpl.java:154)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildAll(KieBuilderImpl.java:220)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildAll(KieBuilderImpl.java:216)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.core.Builder.build(Builder.java:213)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.core.BuildHelper.build(BuildHelper.java:92)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.core.BuildHelper$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.build(Unknown Source)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.ala.LocalBuildExecConfigExecutor.apply(LocalBuildExecConfigExecutor.java:61)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.ala.LocalBuildExecConfigExecutor.apply(LocalBuildExecConfigExecutor.java:32)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.ala.LocalBuildExecConfigExecutor$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.apply(Unknown Source)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.guvnor.ala.pipeline.execution.PipelineExecutor.lambda$continuePipeline$0(PipelineExecutor.java:109)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.guvnor.ala.pipeline.StageUtil$1.execute(StageUtil.java:38)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.guvnor.ala.pipeline.StageUtil$1.execute(StageUtil.java:33)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.guvnor.ala.pipeline.execution.PipelineExecutor.continuePipeline(PipelineExecutor.java:94)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.guvnor.ala.pipeline.execution.PipelineExecutor.execute(PipelineExecutor.java:76)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.ala.BuildPipelineInvoker.invokeLocalBuildPipeLine(BuildPipelineInvoker.java:88)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.ala.BuildPipelineInvoker$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.invokeLocalBuildPipeLine(Unknown Source)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.service.BuildServiceHelper.invokeLocalBuildPipeLine(BuildServiceHelper.java:152)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.service.BuildServiceHelper.localBuild(BuildServiceHelper.java:82)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.service.BuildServiceHelper$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.localBuild(Unknown Source)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.service.BuildServiceImpl.build(BuildServiceImpl.java:69)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.service.BuildServiceImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.build(Unknown Source)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.service.BuildInfoService.getBuildInfo(BuildInfoService.java:59)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.service.BuildInfoService$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getBuildInfo(Unknown Source)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.project.ModuleClassLoaderHelper.getModuleClassLoader(ModuleClassLoaderHelper.java:40)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.project.ModuleClassLoaderHelper$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getModuleClassLoader(Unknown Source)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.kie.workbench.common.screens.datamodeller.backend.server.indexing.JavaFileIndexer.getModuleClassLoader(JavaFileIndexer.java:154)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.kie.workbench.common.screens.datamodeller.backend.server.indexing.JavaFileIndexer.fillIndexBuilder(JavaFileIndexer.java:135)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.kie.workbench.common.services.refactoring.backend.server.indexing.AbstractFileIndexer.toKObject(AbstractFileIndexer.java:78)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.kie.workbench.common.screens.datamodeller.backend.server.indexing.JavaFileIndexer$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.toKObject(Unknown Source)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.uberfire.ext.metadata.io.IndexerDispatcher$IndexerJob.processNew(IndexerDispatcher.java:261)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.uberfire.ext.metadata.io.IndexableIOEvent$NewFileEvent.apply(IndexableIOEvent.java:62)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.uberfire.ext.metadata.io.IndexerDispatcher$IndexerJob.processEvent(IndexerDispatcher.java:241)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.uberfire.ext.metadata.io.IndexerDispatcher$IndexerJob.processEvents(IndexerDispatcher.java:217)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.uberfire.ext.metadata.io.IndexerDispatcher$IndexerJob.get(IndexerDispatcher.java:194)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.uberfire.ext.metadata.io.IndexerDispatcher$IndexerJob.get(IndexerDispatcher.java:165)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.RealmFilteredBeans$FilteredItr.next(RealmFilteredBeans.java:118)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.RealmFilteredBeans$FilteredItr.next(RealmFilteredBeans.java:1)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.DefaultPlexusBeans$Itr.next(DefaultPlexusBeans.java:76)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.DefaultPlexusBeans$Itr.next(DefaultPlexusBeans.java:1)
    at deployment.business-central.war//org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    ... 58 more

16:20:36,842 WARN  [org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenProjectLoader] (Thread-198) Unable to parse pom.xml file of the running project: org.appformer.maven.integration.embedder.MavenEmbedderException: java.util.NoSuchElementException
      role: org.apache.maven.execution.MavenExecutionRequestPopulator
  roleHint: 
16:20:36,857 INFO  [org.appformer.maven.integration.MavenRepository] (Thread-198) Erasing directory from local maven repository /opt/jboss/.m2/repository/org/kie/kie-api/7.40.0.Final
16:20:36,857 INFO  [org.appformer.maven.integration.MavenRepository] (Thread-200) Erasing directory from local maven repository /opt/jboss/.m2/repository/org/kie/kie-api/7.40.0.Final
16:20:36,857 INFO  [org.appformer.maven.integration.MavenRepository] (Thread-197) Erasing directory from local maven repository /opt/jboss/.m2/repository/org/kie/kie-api/7.40.0.Final
16:20:36,857 INFO  [org.appformer.maven.integration.MavenRepository] (default task-11) Erasing directory from local maven repository /opt/jboss/.m2/repository/org/kie/kie-api/7.40.0.Final
16:20:36,859 WARN  [org.appformer.maven.integration.MavenRepository] (Thread-199) The expected local maven repo dir for org.kie:kie-api:7.40.0.Final does not exist /opt/jboss/.m2/repository/org/kie/kie-api/7.40.0.Final, nothing to delete.
16:20:36,859 WARN  [org.appformer.maven.integration.MavenRepository] (Thread-195) The expected local maven repo dir for org.kie:kie-api:7.40.0.Final does not exist /opt/jboss/.m2/repository/org/kie/kie-api/7.40.0.Final, nothing to delete.
16:20:36,858 INFO  [org.appformer.maven.integration.MavenRepository] (Thread-201) Erasing directory from local maven repository /opt/jboss/.m2/repository/org/kie/kie-api/7.40.0.Final
16:20:36,863 WARN  [org.appformer.maven.integration.MavenRepository] (Thread-196) The expected local maven repo dir for org.kie:kie-api:7.40.0.Final does not exist /opt/jboss/.m2/repository/org/kie/kie-api/7.40.0.Final, nothing to delete.
```

Answer (score 0):

i figure out that it require a maven path so i provided my local maven and it run like a miracle.

```
docker run -i -p 8080:8080  --mount type=bind,source=$HOME/.m2,target=/opt/jboss/.m2 --name jbpm-server-full jboss/jbpm-server-full:latest
```